# How to move an article to another place.

Tags: nodes

I just add 10 articles in my drupalwebsite, but now I want to change the place of my articles.

The article that I have added first is now at the bottom. This should be at the top. Everything is in reverse order. How can I change this?

Thx for helping.

Comment: Where do you see above list ? In front page or the page created using views ?

Answer (score 2):

- Promoted to home page content is ordered by created data.. So, Change authored date accordingly..
- Make them sticky by editing content and checking sticky at top of lists checkbox to place them on top of list in home page..
- If you are using [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module you can set sort criteria..

[image]